# Multi-Plot in a single frame using 'for' loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new in Python. I tried this parametric plot in Python where `r` changes with theta (`t`) and is obtained by Numerical integration. Here the parameter `b` is fixed. But I want five plots of the function in the same canvas for five different values of `b` (i.e. 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6) keeping all the other parameters fixed. I hope introducing a for loop would do it, so I tried hard. But it seems that the loop does not work to catch the values and I'm getting the plot for the first value (i.e. `b = 4`) only. Can anyone help?

I am attaching the code I used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

alpha = 0.2
M = 1

for i in np.arange(1,6):
    b = np.arange(4,6,0.5)

F= lambda t, r: (r**2 * ((1/len(b)**2) - ((1 - (2*(1+alpha)*M)/ r + (alpha*(1+alpha)*M**2)/ (r**2))/r**2))**0.5)

t_eval=np.arange(0, 2*np.pi,0.0001)

sol=solve_ivp(F,[0,2*np.pi],[2.3],method='RK45',t_eval=t_eval)

x3 = sol.y[0] * np.cos(sol.t)
y3 = sol.y[0] * np.sin(sol.t)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.xlim(-16,16)
plt.ylim(-16,16)
plt.plot(x3,y3)

plt.show()
```

Output of the above code:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihJmO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. Protip for subplots... Type a description of what you want on google + python , then click "images", then click an image that you like/looks like what you want... I used ["stackoverflow python four  subplots grid"](https://google.gprivate.com/search.php?images/search?q=stackoverflow%20python%20four%20%20subplots%20grid)... I got [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) among others...

Anyway, the thing is you seem to want to split your plot to sub-plots. To do this, youll have to spesify the layout of the subplots, then when plotting you ll need to plot to a specific subplot... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372380/matplotlib-repositioning-a-subplot-in-a-grid-of-subplots) you can find some code of what I am talking about...

Comment: But can I impose all the five plots in a single frame using subplot?

Comment: please explain what is a  frame for you. Does this mean you want to plot all your lines in one plot?

Comment: like https://google.gprivate.com/search.php?images/search?q=stackoverflow+python+multiple+lines+in+one+plot&FORM=HDRSC3 ?

Comment: yes, I want all the lines in one plot @ntg